# Todays datetime in asp-for helper MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get todays datetime (`YYYY-MM-DD`) to show up as default in my box where I choose date. 
Any ideas what I can do to show the `MAX` part as todays date by default. Guess I can create a variable and set it to today's date and use it but are there any easier way, like I'm trying to do it with a `max="something"`??

```
 <input type="date" asp-for="MovingAverageViewModel.StartDate" id="StartDateAnvanceradSMA" value="MovingAverageViewModel.StartDate" class="form-control" max="DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();" min="2017-01-01" />
```

Comment: Not related by remove `value="MovingAverageViewModel.StartDate"` (never set the `value` attribute when using a TagHelper - its already done by the helper). And to format it as `yyyy-MM-dd` then use `DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: the value="MovingAverageViewModel.StartDate" I used as I have multiple boxes with input choices so to know which box this is refering to? 


Do I need to write the it like max="DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" or do I need to use any sort of (); ?


Thanks for the help

Comment: `asp-for="MovingAverageViewModel.StartDate"` means you binding to the value of your property which add the `value` attribute (do not set it yourself under any circumstances). As for the `maxdate` - try it )

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this syntax did the trick: 


max="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Stephen, the answer: max="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"